# Is this a gerund? Relative clause? "오신 것"

Tags: translation

기숙사에 오신 것을 환영합니다 = thanks for coming to the dorm.

I don't think "오신 것" is a gerund because gerunds are in the present tense:
E.g. "오시는 것" = coming

I don't thinks it's a relative clause because it should be "분" then not "것"
"오신 것" = something that came
* sounds rude referring to a person as a "thing"(것)
"오신 분" = people that came - sounds ok.

So what type of grammtical structure is "오신 것" here?

Comment: 것 = that // 기숙사에 오신 것을 환영합니다. = I/We welcome that you came to the dormitory. = Welcome to the dormitory.

Comment: The (bound) noun 것 means *the fact* here. The subjects for the verbs 오다 and 환영하다 are omitted. 오신 것을 환영하다 is a clumsy translation for "Welcome to ...." A lot of Koreans use and accept this construction without thinking about the proper use of 환영하다. According to [the standard dictionary](https://stdict.korean.go.kr/search/searchView.do?word_no=379685&searchKeywordTo=3), 환영하다 needs to have a person (or a group of people) as its direct object, so they should have said something like "기숙사에 오신 **여러분**을 환영합니다."

Comment: Wow, I got so used to that `오신 것` because of League of Legends. "소환사의 협곡에 오신 것을 환영합니다." Nobody really cared that it was a mistranslation all this time. A big +1 to @Klmo.

Comment: In the past, people didn't use the word 환영 itself to welcome people - the word literally means "the act of welcoming someone."  It's almost like saying "greetings!" in English - while possible, not very common.  IIRC they became widespread when MS Windows and other softwares had "welcome screens" and they decided to translate it into 환영합니다. A more natural way to say it in Korean would be simply: (기숙사에) 어서 오세요.

Comment: So is the literal translation for 기숙사에 오신 것을 환영합니다 =  "I welcome the fact that you came to the dorm." ??

Comment: The sentence doesn’t write `사실`(= the fact). So its literal meaning is more closer to "I welcome that you came to the dorm." like I said. Sentences using 환영 like that are supposed to be wrong but have become acceptable to nowadays people because over time, the usage of `환영` changed as suggested by @jick and @Klmo.

Comment: Apparently whether 환영하다 should be strictly used for person/people or it can be used for objects/abstract concepts is highly debatable. According to [this Q&A](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=183158&pageIndex=1), even the national institute requires some discussions, and it is also probable that such usage has been prevalent for a quite long time (even before the standard dictionary) but the dictionary simply failed to list them, and it indeed has some precedences like in cases for 석식 and 미주.

Comment: Can we use 환영 against anything or people only? To me it delivers its meaning either way, while it does make the sentence sound better and more natural when 환영하다 gets a person/people as its direct object.

Comment: In everyday use of modern Korean, it is definitely fine to use 환영하다 to anything. For example, even in the news broadcasts, "시민단체들은 새로운 법안의 입법을 환영했다" (NGOs welcomed the legislation of the new law) or similar is used quite often. Even in the Incheon Int'l Airport it is written as "한국에 오신 걸 환영합니다". I am not sure if this is "incorrect" to use so, and I am not sure since when we have been using in this manner, but it is being used in this way and I believe it will be a standard within a couple of decades if not already.

Comment: @HojinCho They removed that example ("... 제안을 ... 환영했다.") from the standard dictionary, which means that they have not accepted such usage yet. [연세 현대 한국어사전](https://ilis.yonsei.ac.kr/dic/?keyword=%ED%99%98%EC%98%81%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4&id=75565), however, provides examples for both people and things. This dictionary has another definition: 기쁘게 받아들이다. Because the current standard definition starts with **오는 사람을**, we should use 환영하다 for people only.

Comment: Nonetheless, the standard is the standard; we can use 환영하다 against things since we already got familiar with such usage. I would add that 환송하다, the antonym of 환영하다, is used against people only even in 연세 현대 한국어사전. I am just curious why people never say "...에 오셨음을 환영합니다" if it is definitely fine to use 환영하다 against things.

Comment: This is gonna be a debate as worthless as "짜장면 vs 자장면". Well, yeah, I guess by standard as of this day 환영하다 should be used with someone as its object. But non-standard languages are also languages and because of that the meaning of words can change over time. `오신 것을 환영` is in fact a pretty popular expression as mentioned by Hojin Cho. And as it gets more and more popular it may even get listed in the dictionary.

Comment: @Kimo Thank you for pointing out they removing such example from the standard dictionary, but I am not sure if that definitely say they do not accept such definition. What I understand is that such example does not fit with the definition about 오는 사람을 환영하다 so they removed, as you pointed out. But other dictionaries do have extended meaning, so it should be a matter of debate, which, I think, is a reason they have not addressed this yet in one of their Q&As (and out of curiosity I just made a ticket asking for the update on this, let's wait and see.).

Comment: @Kimo Also, 무정 by 이광수, which is considered to be the first modern novel in Korean and predates the standard dictionary, has this usage. ([look for chapter 70, penultimate paragraph](https://thirdblack.tistory.com/entry/%EC%9D%B4%EA%B4%91%EC%88%98-%EB%AC%B4%EC%A0%95-%EC%A0%84%EB%AC%B8%EC%9E%A5%ED%8E%B8%EC%9D%B4%EB%9D%BC-%EB%A1%9C%EB%94%A9%EC%9D%B4-%EC%9E%88%EC%9D%84-%EC%88%98-%EC%9E%88%EC%8A%B5%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4)). This is why I believe the standard dictionary just simply failed to address this secondary meaning and not intentionally dropped such usages out of prevalence or historicity.

Comment: Although the standard does not always apply to literary works (IIRC, 무정 was published even before 한글 마춤법 통일안), I fully understand your points. I am not sure whether it is a valid statement, but the distinction between people and things seems somewhat blurred now. 환영하다's case is similar to [싣다](https://www.korean.go.kr/nkview/news/93/8_6.htm)'s; I suppose they will add the meaning if several people point it out to them.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `것` in this sentence is neither a gerund nor a relative clause. It is used to mark a subordinate clause as in that-clause of English. The difference is that the subject of the clause is implied in the form of the verb `오신`.

- `오다` = to come
- `오시다` = to come (Adding 시 to the verb 오다 specifies the subject so you know *someone honorable* is coming.)
- `오신` = came
- `오시는` = is coming

---

#### Translation

> (저는) (손님께서) 기숙사에 오신 것을 환영합니다.

- I welcome that you came to the dormitory.

---

#### How it works

The sentence can be split into these two phrases:

1. 저는 ~을 환영합니다.
2. 손님께서 기숙사에 오셨다.

In order to put the second sentence inside the first one, we have to turn it into the form `~한 것` or `~하였음`.

1. 손님께서 기숙사에 오신 것

- This is Japanese style influenced by [this](https://kawakawalearningstudio.com/all/koto-mean-using-koto/) grammar structure; 것 = Koto (事 or こと)

2. 손님께서 기숙사에 오셨음

And then merge them:

1. (저는 손님께서) 기숙사에 오신 것을 환영합니다.
2. (저는 손님께서) 기숙사에 오셨음을 환영합니다.